# Buildfire How to setup Firebase to retrieve and update plugin data

Tags: buildfire

I am trying to use Firebase to connect to the Buildfire plugins to manage, update, and retrieve data. Is this only possible for plugins created from scratch. How do I use firebase to connect to app data.

Answer (score 1):

BuildFire is not built on a monolithic database. Furthermore, each plugin can a autonomous. It can save its data in any of the BuildFire built in databases or its own.

As for Google Firebase there are some existing Features/Plugins the use dedicated Firebase/Firestore instances to avoid a multi-tenant database for compliance reasons.

While BuildFire allows you to connect to firebase through a plug-in instance. You will sometimes need use your data outside of your plug-in for authentication, roles and permission. BuildFire provides the ability to integrate on the backend to your Firebase instance using the developer portal.
See more here https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Buildfire-Firebase-Integration

In conclusion, You probably would need to create your plug-in from scratch to use the database of your choice Firebase or anything else. And when you do so it will only have your plug-ins data.

Comment: Thanks that brings some clarity to my development process. What would you recommend the best approach for the following.

A plugin to collect responses from app users(currently I'm using a Microsoft form).

A plugin to display those responses as a list that can show details from the form. (Currently I am using a list plugin, and workingon a rest api to get and post data)

Comment: Outside of just webview'ing in the form which isnt a great solution. There is the Questioner plugin that would do what you are looking for, store the results in BuildFire but also POST to your API as well.

Comment: If you are looking for a completely custom plugin. You can build the plugin with the form submitter on the Widget side, Save it to the BF User Data DB or your Firebase DB, then show the aggregate results on the Control side of the plugin. So the app owner can see all the results. Very Similar to the Questioner plugin